# Button Control in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developping a Wp 8.1 app. I have some Buttons named Btn1, Btn2, Btn3....
I'm looking for something like this:

```
int i;

for (i = 0 ; i <= 10 ; i++)
{
   Btn(Convert.ToString(i)).ImageSource = ".......";
}
```

Someone can help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: No built in "eval", so might as well just find the control by name: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Unclear what exactly you're trying to do here, but databinding is probably the key. Possibly databind the image itself but more likely bind some sort of state and then show an appropriate image based on that.

Comment: @Rob but with databinding how can I decide whether to use an image rather than another? I have to change only one button image when i tap it

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do? There are too many possibilities to enumerate them all without knowing what you need

Comment: When I tap a button , others button images have to change

Answer (score 0):

Either you add the images one by one e.g.

```
Btn1.ImageSource = ".......";
Btn2.ImageSource = ".......";
Btn3.ImageSource = ".......";
....
```

Or if you really wanted to do the loop method you could add all of the buttons to an array or list and iterate over them

e.g.

```
foreach(var button in ButtonList)
{
    button.ImageSource = ".......";
}
```

Do you really have that many buttons that you need to loop over and set them though?

Comment: Thanks @Daniel for the answer. The first solution is logical but I want to avoid it because I have a lot of Buttons. I'll tried the second one. Thanks.

Comment: actually my problem is that when a button is tapped, the others have to change image

Comment: iterate through the button collection as suggested but while doing that compare the object to the sender and use a conditional to do one thing if its not the one clicked and another if it is.

Comment: Ok, @Wobbles. Thanks.

Comment: @Daniel I found this solution: 

<Button Name="btn1" Click="GetName_Click"/>
<Button Name="btn2" Click="GetName_Click"/>
<Button Name="btn3" Click="GetName_Click"/>

private void GetName_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = sender as Button;
            if(btn.Name=="btn1")
            {
                //selected button name is 'btn1'
            }
            ......
        }

Mauro